# Uses of reentrant code?

Tags: reentrancy

What are examples of types of applications or methods that should be reentrant? Or is it something that you should generally strive for?

Also, is it generally a given in (pure) functional programming that your code will be reentrant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code has no side-effects whatsoever (which happens if it's 'purely functional'), it's re-entrant *and* thread-safe.

In UI development you encounter reentrancy issues. You get one UI event and start a chain of events that may cause the same event to fire before your first handler was done.